# Norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $A+A^H-\delta I_n$ is positive-semidefinite, for some $\delta>0$, then can we show a bound on the norm of $A^{-1}$ ?
Can we show that this the norm of the inverse of $A$ is at most $2/\delta$ ?
(The norm is the usual matrix 2-norm)

Let me briefly describe my approach. Please correct me if I am wrong.

By the positive semi-definiteness condition, we obtain that $v^H (A+A^H) v \geq \delta$,  $\forall v$ of norm $1$. So the norm of $A+A^H$ is at least $\delta$, and using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we obtain a lower bound on the norm of $A$ as $\delta /2$. But this does not seem to help in upper bounding the norm of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: I changed $n*n$ to $n\times n$, coded as n\times n.  $\TeX$ is sophisticated.  The asterisk for multiplication is a workaround for use when you can only use symbols on the keyboard and "x" must be available as a variable.  So it amounts to eating mashed potatoes with your fingers when silverware is right there.  Also, I changed $\delta$$>$$0$ to $\delta>0$, with all three symbols inside just one instance of $\TeX$  That way you get proper spacing between characters.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am relatively new to TEX and hope to improve with more usage.

Comment: It's sufficient to consider this question for $\delta = 1$.

Comment: @all: I deleted some comments about topology which is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any nonzero vector $u$,  $$\|u\| \|A u\| \ge |u^H A u| \ge \text{Re}(u^H A u) = u^H (A + A^H) u/2 \ge \delta \|u\|^2/2$$ so $\|Au\| \ge \delta \|u\|/2$, which implies that $A$ is invertible with
$\|A^{-1}\| \le 2/\delta$.

Comment: This only gives a lower bound on the norm of $A$, as I mentioned as part of my attempt. How did you conclude that $A$ is invertible and upper bound the norm of its inverse?

Comment: No, it gives a lower bound on the norm of $A u$ for *every* nonzero $u$. 
 
1) If a square matrix is invertible, its null space is nonzero, so there would be $u \ne 0$ with $\|A u\| = 0 < \delta \|u\|/2$.

2) Take $u = A^{-1} v$ to get $\|v\| \ge \delta \|A^{-1} v\|/2$.